# Export PCA components in r

Tags: r, components, pca

I did pca on my data using r and I am trying to save the components with an eigenvalue larger than 1.

```
> summary(pca1)
Importance of components:
                          Comp.1    Comp.2    Comp.3    Comp.4    Comp.5     Comp.6     Comp.7     Comp.8
Standard deviation     1.2851803 1.1245020 1.0737268 1.0011978 0.9841687 0.88758402 0.84798807 0.67308490
Proportion of Variance 0.2064611 0.1580631 0.1441112 0.1252996 0.1210735 0.09847567 0.08988547 0.05663041
Cumulative Proportion  0.2064611 0.3645241 0.5086353 0.6339349 0.7550084 0.85348412 0.94336959 1.00000000
> loadings(pca1)

Loadings:
                            Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8
AspectRatio                  0.604         0.325                0.230  0.194  0.652
CPUSpeed                     0.241                0.278  0.890 -0.242              
IsDvrEnabled                 0.428        -0.329 -0.109 -0.290 -0.724 -0.281       
ZoomMode                     0.123         0.837        -0.133 -0.232 -0.124 -0.432
Tuner_BitRate                0.600        -0.272                0.392  0.161 -0.616
Tuner_Hole                                       -0.948  0.306                     
Receiver_VideoDecoderErrors        -0.705                       0.283 -0.640       
Receiver_AudioDecoderErrors -0.128 -0.690                      -0.275  0.650       

               Comp.1 Comp.2 Comp.3 Comp.4 Comp.5 Comp.6 Comp.7 Comp.8
SS loadings     1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000  1.000
Proportion Var  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125  0.125
Cumulative Var  0.125  0.250  0.375  0.500  0.625  0.750  0.875  1.000
```

So in this case I am interested in the first four components.
Is there a way that I can save it in a table or a file (file is proffered).
Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many ways to subset and save tables to files.

Comment: I tried using rotation but I am not sure that it did the right thing.

Comment: `write.csv(unclass(loadings(pca1)), file = "pca.loadings.csv")`?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I assume that there is no easy way to export only the ones with eigenvalue larger than 1, correct?

Comment: `unclass(loadings(pca1))[,(pca1$sdev^2 > 1)]` `pca1$sdev^2` is the eigenvalue.

Comment: @Vlo you should add your answer below so it can be accepted and thereby close this question.

Comment: VIo I can't be thankful enough! And yes, please write it as the answer so I could select it and close this thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`loadings(pca1)` returns the PCA Loadings. `unclass` drops the class and converts it into a `matrix`.

`pca1$sdev^2 > 1` returns `TRUE` for columns where the eigenvalue > 1. `[...,drop = F]` selects the columns where the index is equals to `TRUE` while keeping the matrix structure even when only one column is selected. `write.csv` writes the results to a file.

Final Code: `write.csv(x = unclass(loadings(pca1))[,(pca1$sdev^2 > 1),drop = FALSE], file = "filename.csv")`